# How to highlight search keyword using php preg_replace with parentheses?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to highlight my keyword search text by using preg_replace in php but the problem is it won't work with parentheses string `(` and `)`

My function look like this...

```
$text_oritinal = "25 Hours: Colour In White (CD)";

function highlight($text_search, $text_original) {
  $str = preg_replace('#'. $text_search .'#i', '<span style="background-color:#FFFF66; color:#FF0000;">\\0</span>', $text_original);
  return $str;
}
```

Full original text is `"25 Hours: Colour In White (CD)"`

For example. If I use the keyword

```
$text_search = "25 Hours: Colour In White";
```

It return good replaced keyword with highlight background and text color.

```
<span style="background-color:#FFFF66; color:#FF0000;">25 Hours: Colour In White</span> (CD)
```

but! if I use this keyword included parentheses string `(` and `)`

```
$text_search = "25 Hours: Colour In White (CD)";
```

It NOT return replaced background and text color.

I think it stuck with parentheses string `(` and `)`

The question is how to highlight all text keyword matched without any problem with parentheses string `(` and `)`?

Please share your idea. Thanks :)

Comment: Do not remove your question when editing. It makes asking the question useless.

Comment: I will do as your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```
function highlight($text_highlight, $text_search) {
  $str = preg_replace('#'. preg_quote($text_highlight) .'#i', '<span style="background-color:#FFFF66; color:#FF0000;">\\0</span>', $text_search);
  return $str;
}
```

Explanation:

Parenthesis are used to create `submatches`. Using them in your search string, will cause undesired results as they are reserved characters. You can prevent this, and other characters by using `preg_quote` which escapes regex reserved characters.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text you put into the regex in preg_quote

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php